# 'System.Data.DataRowView' in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, using-statement

I cannot bind data to a `Dropdown List`.. Can any one explain me why?
Error is : `'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name '_DeptID'.`
my code is:

```
public class ClassDataManagement
{
    public DataTable BindDropDownList(string Sql, DropDownList DropDownList)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ABID-PC;Initial Catalog=_uniManagement;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
            DropDownList.DataValueField = "_DeptID";
            DropDownList.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
            DropDownList.DataBind();
        }
        return dt;
    }

}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassDataManagement dm = new ClassDataManagement();
    dm.BindDropDownList("select _Program.Name from _program,_Department where _program._Deptid = _department._DeptId", DropDownListProgram);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The column _Dept is missing in your select statement
2. Disposing of the objects is missing. So you can perform it in two ways

   (a) Manually disposing

   (b) Using Statement

---

```
public class ClassDataManagement
{
    public DataTable BindDropDownList(string Sql, DropDownList DropDownList)
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ABID-PC;Initial Catalog=_uniManagement;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, cn))
            {
                using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        DropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
                        DropDownList.DataValueField = "_Deptid";
                        DropDownList.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                        DropDownList.DataBind();
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassDataManagement dm = new ClassDataManagement();
    dm.BindDropDownList("select _Program.Name, _program._Deptid from _program,_Department "
        + "where _program._Deptid = _department._DeptId", DropDownListProgram);

}
```

**EDIT - 1**

Adding the Using Statement for **SqlDataAdapter** as well

Answer (score 4):

You aren't returning a column called `_Deptid` in your SQL statement.

Your SQL statement should read:

```
select _program.Name, _program._Deptid 
  from _program,_Department 
 where _program._Deptid = _Department._DeptId
```

As Stackoverflow User has mentioned, by using the `using` statement, this will automatically dispose of your objects.  Another thing, you are doing:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
```

but you have no code within it.  Whether you do in your actual code or not, but if you are intending on leaving it blank, it would be advisable to do:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";    
    DropDownList.DataValueField = "_DeptID";    
    DropDownList.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;    
    DropDownList.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your SQL to:

```
select _Program.Name, _Program._DeptId from _program,_Department where _program._Deptid = _department._DeptId
```

Answer (score 3):

Try modifing your code to this, you are missing `_DeptID`

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassDataManagement dm = new ClassDataManagement();
        dm.BindDropDownList("select _Program.Name,_DeptID from _program,_Department where _program._Deptid = _department._DeptId", DropDownListProgram);

    }
```